# Rails namespaced model conflicting with non-namespaced model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, namespaces

I have two classes in rails 3.2.6:

- class Foo  in models/foo.rb (is in table foos, per default)
- class Bar::Foo in models/bar/foo.rb (which sets `self.table_name` to `bar_foos`)

When I go into console, I get:

```
> Bar::Foo
=> Bar::Foo(id: ...)
> Foo # or ::Foo
LoadError: expected models/bar/foo.rb to define Foo
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We solved this in IRC, but the core issue is that there was a `config.autoload_paths` glob set that was including `models/**` as load paths.

Rails' auto-loader iterates the load paths, and tacks on the constant name. Once it finds a file that exists, it tries to load it, then throws an exception if the constant is not available.

So, what was happening is Rails had a list of load paths like:

```
/models/bar/
/models/
```

It was iterating the paths, and would find a match at `/models/bar/foo.rb`, which it then loads (which makes `Bar::Foo` available, but not `Foo`), then throws the exception because `Foo` isn't available.

The solution in this case was to remove the `autoload_paths` setting, so that Rails would not find the wrong file to load for the root-level constant.

Answer (score 2):

Turns out that this line in config/applications.rb was the problem:

```rb
 config.autoload_paths += Dir[Rails.root.join('app', 'models', '{**}')]
```

With explicitly set autoload, Rails got confused; rather than look under models/ by namespacing appropriately, it looked at the first autoload file it had (which was, mistakenly, models/bar/foo.rb) and found (true) that it failed to define Foo (it defines Bar::Foo).

So evidently Rails 3 already knows to look in models/ subdirs for namespaced models.

Thanks to Antiarc on freenode #RubyOnRails for helping figure this out.